# Flutter Just_audio, Error No implementation found for method disposeAllPlayers

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I am using [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) package to play my base64 string which is a wav file that I received from my server. The app is being played from an android device API 30-ish. This is the error once the base64 is loaded:

```
E/flutter (31770): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method disposeAllPlayers on channel com.ryanheise.just_audio.methods)
E/flutter (31770): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
E/flutter (31770): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31770): #1      MethodChannelJustAudio.disposeAllPlayers (package:just_audio_platform_interface/method_channel_just_audio.dart:29:10)
E/flutter (31770): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31770): 
E/flutter (31770): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel com.ryanheise.just_audio.methods)
E/flutter (31770): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
E/flutter (31770): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31770): #1      MethodChannelJustAudio.init (package:just_audio_platform_interface/method_channel_just_audio.dart:13:5)
E/flutter (31770): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31770): #2      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1330:13)
E/flutter (31770): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31770):
```

My custom base64 player which I follow from the instruction of the page:

```
class MyAudioPlayer extends StreamAudioSource {
  MyAudioPlayer({this.bytes});

  List<int> bytes;

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int start, int end]) async {
    final start = 0;
    final end = bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: "audio/x-wav",
    );
  }
}
```

The file in which I played:

```
  void playTTS(String content) async{
    Dialogs.showLoadingDialog(context: context);
    final List<int> base64 = await ApiService.textToSpeech(content);
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    await player.setAudioSource(MyAudioPlayer(bytes: base64));
    await player.play();
    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
    listString.value = List.from(listString.value..add(ValueNotifier(content)));
  }
```

I have set already set this to my androidmanifest.xml to true already.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to narrow down whether it has anything at all to do with your base64 use case, or whether it is some other conflicting plugin in your app, etc. Is your question necessarily concerning all that base64 code? What I mean is, if you replace `player.setAudioSource` temporarily with `player.setUrl` and pass in a regular URL like the official example, does it still produce the same error? If so, then you can remove the base64 part from your question and simplify it for us.

Comment: I quite don't understand the last part. But yes, it does have to do with Base64 and wav file. I have used `player.setUrl` and it's fine. The only problem is playing the audio from the Base64. Yes, I have tested my Base64 by converting it online and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I don't have to convert the base64 Wav file with a custom class like the tutorial did. According to the online converter, all I have to do was put `data:audio/wav;base64,$base64` before the actual base64 string and uses the normal `setUrl` and it worked:

```
 final String code = "data:audio/wav;base64," + json.decode(response.body)["base64"];
 final player = AudioPlayer();
 player.setUrl(code);
 await player.play();
```